# The max of a random sum, SK model

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

Let $(N_{i,j}, i,j \in \mathbb N)$ be independent (standard) Gaussian random variables.

What is known/ what is conjectured /what can we say about

$$\max \lbrace{\sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq n} \epsilon_i \; N_{i,j} \; \epsilon_j \, ; \, \epsilon \in \{-1,1\}^n \rbrace}$$

as $n \to \infty$: First order, second order, … fluctuations?

This is related to the Sherrington-Kirkpatrick model. If $\epsilon$ would be allowed to range over the sphere with radius $\sqrt{n}$ rather than the discrete hypercube $\{-1,1\}^n$, the fluctuations would be Tracy Widom I think.

Comment: Some recent work on the Tracy widom connection "Fluctuations of the free energy of the spherical Sherrington–Kirkpatrick model"